# Applying Filter to Pandas Pivot Table blanks out data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Using the following csv data:
[Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqGcg.png)

I've loaded the data from a csv into a Pandas Pivot Table with the output:

```
[[nan nan nan ... nan nan  0.]
 [nan 21 nan ... nan  0. nan]
 [nan nan nan ...  0. nan nan]
 ...
 [23. nan 13. ... nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
 [nan 14 nan ... nan nan nan]]
```

But after using a Scipy Gaussian filter on the results, the data is then blanked out as below:

```
  [[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
     [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
     [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
     ...
     [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
     [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
     [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]]
```

Is there a way to apply a gaussian filter to the pivot table without it blanking out the data?

Code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage

FILE_PATH = "."
def load_nut_data(file_path=FILE_PATH):
   csv_path = os.path.join(file_path, "csv_file.csv")
   return pd.read_csv(csv_path, usecols = ['GPSLon', 'GPSLat','NutCount'])
 
nut = load_nut_data()
nut.head()
Z = nut.pivot_table(index='GPSLon', columns='GPSLat',
values='NutCount').T.values 
 
print(Z)

Zg= sp.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(Z, sigma, mode='grid-constant')

print(Zg)
```

Answer (score 0):

This filter is implemented as a sequence of 1-D convolution filters. If your data is nostly `nans`, these `nans` get into the convolutions as multipliers and htnce turn the whole convolution results into `nans`. consider replacing `nans` with zeros.